# Quais são as diferenças entre os operadores de comparação em Erlang?

Tags: característica-linguagem, operadores, erlang

Em Erlang, temos os seguintes operadores de comparação:

- `=:=`
- `=/=`
- `==`
- `/=`

É dito que os dois últimos podem ser usados para fazer comparação entre *integers* e *floats*, já que os dois primeiros diferenciam um *integer* de *float*:

```
1 =:= 1.0. % false
1 == 1.0. % true

1 =/= 1.0. % true
1 /= 1.0. % false
```

Além dessa diferença, há alguma outra divergência entre o comportamento entre os operadores `=:=` e `=/=` dos operadores `==` e `/=`?

Comment: Da documentação: ==  Equal to;
/=  Not equal to;
=<  Less than or equal to;
<  Less than;
>=  Greater than or equal to;
>  Greater than;
=:=  Exactly equal to;
=/=  Exactly not equal to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os operadores `==` e `/=` são operadores de equidade, que comparam somente o valor. Já os operadores `=:=` e `=/=` são operadores de identidade, que comparam tipo e valor. Para exemplificar, `=:=` seria equivalente ao [`===`  no JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

A diferença prática foi abordada na pergunta de forma correta. Pode-se comparar um inteiro com um float, de forma que `1 == 1.0. % true` enquanto `1 =:= 1.0. % false`. A implicação técnica é que os operadores de equidade fazem conversão de tipo, o que prejudica a performance.

Vale lembrar que as comparações de [pattern matching](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#match) comparam a identidade dos padrões, de forma que:

```erlang
{X, 3.0} = {2, 3}.
% ** exception error: no match of right hand side value {2,3}

{X, 3} = {2, 3}.
% {2,3}
```